# Clear and reset user's JWT token in local storage with same action

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt, express-jwt

I'm making a component where users can change their details, and the way I'm doing it is that they are essentially deleting their account and remaking it - doing this with Redux and JWT. If there's a better way of doing this, please let me know, but for now this is doing the trick for me.

When a user first creates an account, it sets their JWT token with the correct details in the local storage. That works fine. It also sets it no problem when they log in.

The problem is that when they call the "edit" function, which deletes their account and creates a new one, the above is not happening. So if I create an account with username "aaa", the application shows that with the key of profile and the values I created. But when I call edit it - to username "bbb" for example, even though a new account *is* successfully created (shows up in my MongoDB, can be logged into), it is *not* updating the token properly - the values for the key are showing as an empty object of {}.

Is there a simple way to clear *and then* update the token that I am missing? Would love a hand!

My actions are here:

```
import * as api from "../api";
import { AUTH, DELETE } from "./ActionTypes";

export const signin = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.signIn(formData)

    dispatch({ type: AUTH, data })

    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const signup = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.signUp(formData)
    
    dispatch({ type: AUTH, data })

    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};


export const editProfile = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {

    const { data } = await api.editProfile(formData)
    const { data2 } = await api.signUp(formData)

    Promise.resolve(dispatch({ type: DELETE, data })).then(
    () => dispatch({ type: AUTH, data2 }))

    history.push("/profile");

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error here", error);
  }
};
```

And my reducers are here:

```
import { AUTH, LOGOUT, EDIT, REFRESH } from "../actions/ActionTypes";

const authReducer = (state = { authData: null }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH:
      localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify({...action?.data}));

      return {...state, authData: action.data};
      break;
    case LOGOUT:
    
        localStorage.clear()
        return {...state, authData: null};

      return state;
      break;

    case EDIT:

      localStorage.clear()
      return {...state, authData: null};

    default:
      return state;
      break;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

My GitHub for the project is here: https://github.com/gordonmaloney/lingr-mern/

(As an aside, I had spent all day trying to work out how I might be able to patch the details before giving up and coming to Stack Overflow to ask, but as I was typing up my question it dawned on me that I could try doing it by just deleting and recreating, and I'm now *SO CLOSE* to getting it where I want that this last little bump is really frustrating me!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out!

It was because both reducers were looking for action.data, which is how the sign up action was called originally. But because it was called "data2" when called as part of the edit action, it wasn't finding anything to update the token with. I changed the names and now it works perfectly.

For reference, the new code is below:

Actions:

```
import * as api from "../api";
import { AUTH, DELETE } from "./ActionTypes";

export const signin = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.signIn(formData)

    dispatch({ type: AUTH, data })

    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const signup = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.signUp(formData)
    
    dispatch({ type: AUTH, data })

    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};


export const editProfile = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {

    const { data2 } = await api.editProfile(formData)
    const { data } = await api.signUp(formData)

    await dispatch({ type: DELETE, data2 });

    await dispatch({ type: AUTH, data });

    history.push("/profile");

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Reducers:

```
import { AUTH, LOGOUT, EDIT, REFRESH } from "../actions/ActionTypes";

const authReducer = (state = { authData: null }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH:
      localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify({...action?.data}));

      console.log(action)

      return {...state, authData: action.data};
      break;

    case LOGOUT:
    
        localStorage.clear()
        return {...state, authData: null};
      break;

    case EDIT:

      localStorage.clear()
      localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify({...action?.data2}));
      return {...state, authData: null};

    default:
      return state;
      break;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a little bit of Promises vertigo here. Let's explore the `editProfile` function, this bit in particular:

```js
Promise.resolve(dispatch({ type: DELETE, data })).then(/* ... */)
```

I'll quote docs on `Promise.resolve()`:

> Promise.resolve() method returns a Promise object that is resolved
> with a given value

And `dispatch()` returns a `Promise` itself. So, what you're doing here is wrapping a promise which is returned by `dispatch` into one more promise, immediately resolve this "outer" promise by calling `Promise.resolve()` and then you are dispatching `AUTH` action.

What you should do is:

```js
dispatch({ type: DELETE, data })).then(() => dispatch({ type: AUTH, data2 }));
```

Or, which reads better in my opinion:

```js
await dispatch({ type: DELETE, data });

await dispatch({ type: AUTH, data2 });

history.push("/profile");
```

Which means you'll wait for `dispatch` to finish and then call the second dispatch.

Comment: Hm, this is doing the same thing for me - it's still successfully deleting the old account and creating a new one, but after it runs the localStorage is showing still showing {} as before.

Comment: What if you won't call `dispatch({ type: DELETE })` at all? Looks like `dispatch({ type: AUTH, data2 })` should do the trick for you, cause it rewrites the data on localStorage

Comment: I just worked it out - it was the "data2" that was causing the problem, so I changed it so it is called the same in the AUTH action and the edit one, and now it's working perfectly, although I suspect it wouldn't have been without also making the changes you suggested at first, so thank you very much for that!